# Building Desktop Application

Tags: software-development, desktop-client

I have created a multiplayer game for which I need to create desktop clients for different platforms like windows and mac.
I have used ionic for creating apps for mobiles.
My question is which framework should I use for desktop applications,
I have tried **Electron** but I have heard that the source code is not hidden when creating your.exe files and that the electron app takes up a lot of memory or drain the battery faster(Read an article about it)
There is **CEF** framework but I couldn't understand it much
and then there is **NW.js** also,
My question is which framework should I use so that I can complete the app fast(approx 1 to 2 months)
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. This is definitely the site to ask us to recommend software, but, as you are new, I will point out our sister site [game development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) which might help you in other ways.

Comment: Btw, would [Unity](https://unity.com/) help you?

Comment: Thanks, @Mawg for the reply I cannot use unity we have used HTML 5 gaming framework. I just wanted to know whether the electron or NW framework ideal for desktop client and not cause any problems because CEF is in C++ which will take require some time for me to learn